# logical error with for loop in array

Tags: java, for-loop

Ok so im told there is a slight logical error with my for inner loop. apparently if my [2][2] array had was 2X3 elements or 3X2 elements it wouldnt work could someone tell me how to fix this slight problem?

```
public static void dispArr(String [][] country){
    for(int i= 0; i<country.length; i++){ // both for loops count from 0 to 1 which are the only numbers required for this given array 
        for(int j= 0; j<country.length; j++){
            System.out.print(country[i][j]); //this will output [0][0],[0][1],[1][0] and[1][1] as identified above.
        }

        System.out.println("\n"); //create space between both
    }   
}
```

Comment: Try `country[i].length` in the inner loop

Comment: Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 8):

Change it to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < country.length; i++) {

                     // note the change here
    for (int j = 0; j < country[i].length; j++) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Otherwise, the inner loop won't count up to as much as it needs to.

For a simple example, if you had this:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

It would become (with your original code):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

              // oh no! not counting far enough
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

You have to take **the length of the inner array you're looping over**, not the **amount of inner arrays**, if that makes any sense to you.

Answer (score 2):

In Java a 2 dimensional array is essentially an array of arrays.  Hence the need to put the index of the first dimension (array) when counting the second.

```
public static void dispArr(String [][] country){
    for(int i= 0; i<country.length; i++){ // both for loops count from 0 to 1 which are the only numbers required for this given array 

        for(int j= 0; j<country[i].length; j++){

            System.out.print(country[i][j]); //this will output [0][0],[0][1],[1][0] and[1][1] as identified above.
        }

        System.out.println("\n"); //create space between both
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`country.length` only gives you the first dimension. `country[i].length` will give you the second dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner loop iterates over the first dimension in the matrix, and should probably be

```
for ( int j=0; j < country[i].length; j++ ) { ...
```

instead. Note the `[i]` after `country`.

Cheers,